# Unity error prefab instance problem: "name_prefab" (missing prefab with GUID)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make game with team and use GitHub Desktop. Recently I have this problem with GUID. Every time when I open Unity GUID on 2 prefabs changes and appear this error. Even when I changed GUID in prefab's meta and then open unity GUID changed again.

When I open the GitHub desktop I see 2 changes in prefab's meta (line GUID changes). Guys from my team don't have these errors. Recently, I haven't even opened Unity, only updated the Unity hub to the 3.4.1 version. Could updating the unity hub be a reason for this?

I tried to delete the prefab from the scene and add it from the asset folder again. Also, I changed GUID but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

the solution turned out to be that you need to change all GUID occurrences in the meta file of the scene where errors occurred (I previously changed the GUID only in prefab's meta file)